# Is there any Example to Load .so file Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mupdf

Is there any Example Available to Load .so file in Xamarin.Android ? I have native mupdf code and I need to use that code in Xamarin.Android and create custom views and add Links .

Thanks,
Dharmik

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/SanAngeles_NDK

Comment: @SushiHangover : Thanks for your response . But that's not working. :(

Comment: Have you tried it with Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("NAME_OF_SO_FILE"); ?